# A combinatorial question about basketball match

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have two basketball teams $A,B$ in a match, if their goals' difference never greater than 2 we call them "well-matched".

Assume these two teams totally have 12 goals at end and always in "well-matched" during whole game, how many different game we could have? (e.g. Case 1:Team $A$ have $1^{st},3^{rd},...,11^{th}$ all odd goals, Team $B$ have $2^{nd},4^{th},...,12^{th}$ all even goal. Case 2:Team $B$ have $1^{st},3^{rd},...,11^{th}$ all odd goals, Team $A$ have $2^{nd},4^{th},...,12^{th}$ all even goal).

Here is my solution: I convert this question into a lattice path problem. We consider team $A$ get a goal as move up one unit, and team $B$ get a goal as move right. Then we have a lattice path problem as below:

[A lattice path problem with some restricted area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixO17.png)

So the problem is same as count the lattice path from $(0,0)$ to $(6,6),(5,7),(7,5)$ on bold line.

Unfortunately, I couldn't proceed with my thought since this is not regular lattice path problem I learned before.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: For a small number like this you can just add numbers like Pascal's triangle, considering all the light vertices to be $0$.  Start with $1$ at $(0,0)$.  You might find a pattern you can then prove to be general.

Comment: The approach suggested by @RossMillikan may well be better than what my first try would be.  It seems to me that your *restricted lattice* diagram nicely captures the problem's constraint.  It also seems to me that after $~4~$ moves, you have exactly three mutually exclusive possibilities: (1,3), (2,2) or (3,1).  So, my first try, which might well prove problematic, would be to manually explore each of these 3 cases.  You have the built in shortcut that (3,1), being symmetric to (1,3), does not need exploration.

Comment: @RossMillikan That's a brillian method!!

Answer (score 2):

This problem is equivalent to counting the number of walks of length $12$ starting at the central vertex of a path on $5$ vertices. The vertices of the path represent the difference in score between the two teams, which can only be $+2, +1, 0, -1, -2$. We can only move this difference by one each goal, hence the path graph. A walk starting at $0$ exactly records who made each goal.

The walks of length $n$ are recorded by $A^n$, where $A$ is the adjacency matrix of the graph. Diagonalizing and computing, I get that the number of walks of length $n$ starting at $0$ is $4 \cdot 3^{n/2-1}$ for even $n$, and $2 \cdot 3^{(n-1)/2}$ for odd $n$. So for $n=12$, the answer is $4 \cdot 3^{5}$.

Comment: Thanks! This brings me back to the time I learn Graph theory.